# Kotlin coroutines exception propagation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

I would expect that throwing exception inside any flow will leads to propagation of this exception to coroutine collecting this flow. Nevertheless I'm experiencing quite a different behaviour. For instance considered the following example, which resembles problematic code quite closely:

```
try {
    channelFlow {
        send(1)
        error("random error")
    }.collect {
        println("$it")
    }
} catch (e: CancellationException) {
    println("Unexpected exception: ${e.cause}")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println("Expected exception: $e")
}
```

In this example I'm getting Cancellation exception even when exception is thrown inside a channel flow. Is this a legit behaviour in some case?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. In both my local machine and Kotlin Playground, I get the error we throw: https://pl.kotl.in/o7ScSdUYM What version of Kotlin and coroutines do you use?

Comment: I can't reproduce it using the provided example either. But it is in nutshell the the same code as the production one causing issues. We use Kotlin 1.9.20.

Comment: Without seeing the actual erroneous code it will be hard to provide a fix for it. Can you take your production code and change it step by step until the code looks like the one from your question? If at any step the error vanishes, you have found the problematic code. Post that instead and we can have a look at this again. To make it short: We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Neither the production code does not malfunction every time so I'm not sure whether I would be able to find the problematic lines by commenting them. That was the reason why I asked whether under certain circumstances it is valid to expect exception wrapped into CancellationException rather than how to fix it.

Comment: The documentation specifies that it won’t throw “exceptions used to cancel the coroutine”. CancellationExceptions can come from other sources. Theoretically, these CancellationExceptions would be thrown from the collect.

Comment: I understand that flow is cancelled when the scope used to collect it is cancelled but in such case I would expect the stack trace of the caught exception does not contain frames belonging to the flow body.